# efficient paging with PetaPoco MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, petapoco

Is there any way we could do efficient paging with petapoco and mvc3. At present i am pulling all the records which is certainly not a prefect way to do it.

It was very easy with using LINQ skip() take().

NOTE: this is going to be implemented in an auction portal and database would be massive.

Experts please shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example of how you could do paged queries in the [documentation](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/74/PetaPoco-Paged-Queries). And here's the [new API](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/89/Some-Minor-PetaPoco-Improvements).

Comment: Thanks it helped! I also followed this article. http://snipt.net/dkitchen/tag/mvccontrib